# Tag merge - [disconnect] and [disconnects]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Seems like more or less the same thing, 3 questions on one and 10 questions on the other.  I can manually merge if no one objects.

Comment: Go ahead. (IMO)

Comment: Makes sense to me. I've also added a vote for a new tag synonum from `disconnect` -> `disconnects` based on the fact `disconnects` was larger.

Comment: Opps, forgot to add a [link](http://superuser.com/tags/disconnects/synonyms) to make it easy for others to find and vote on the synonym...

Comment: And we're retagged, thanks all.

Comment: [disconnect] is better than [disconnects] IMO.

Comment: @Sathya - I agree (or maybe `[disconnecting]`?), but `[disconnects]` was being used more widely, so I guess that's what we're stuck with.

Comment: @DMA5 we could've renamed everything to the correct sounding one, but this was [status-completed], so left a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[status-completed]` + there's a synonym mapping for `[disconnect]` -> `[disconnects]`